# Error loading the netbeans module with maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

When I try run the main module I get the following warning of a sub-module named Model-Configuration

```
Warning - could not install some modules: 
Model Configuration - The module named org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner/1 was needed and not found. 
15 further modules could not be installed due to the above problems.
```

I've have already specified the dependency in the pom of Model-Configuration as follows.

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
              <moduleDependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <id>org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-gsf-testrunner</id>
                       <type>impl</type>
                       <explicitValue>org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner/1 = 201508041349</explicitValue>
                   </dependency>
             </moduleDependencies>
         </configuration>
   </plugin>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.netbeans.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-gsf-testrunner</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-options-editor</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.netbeans.modules</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>               
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Any idea how to resolve this? 
Thanks.

EDIT:

Here actually my purpose is to update from netbeans platform RELEASE802 to RELEASE81-BETA. org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner dependency seems to be only problem so far. When omit all the classes that use this dependency, then the application runs fine, without module installation failures.

Comment: That looks like a proelbme with Netbeans...not with maven...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is this line:

```
<explicitValue>org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner/1 = 201508041349</explicitValue>
```

this declares an implementation dependency on the module and effectively ties it to the 8.0 version of the artifact. But at runtime you don't have the 8.0 version but 8.1 and dependency is not satisfied.

When upgrading to 8.1-BETA you need to find that artifact's 8.1-BETA manifest and copy&paste it's implementation here.

Comment: I can't seem to find the manifest for gsf.testrunner 8.1-BETA. Where can I find it? or It is not available for 8.1-BETA ?

Comment: Dunno, maybe it's gone, maybe it was renamed. You might want to check with the NetBeans devs (file an issue)

Answer (score 0):

@mkleint is correct, it was an issue of implementation version, But I couldn't find a workaround for 8.1-BETA. Anyways now 8.1 has been released and with 8.1 release the following worked fine

```
<explicitValue>org.netbeans.modules.gsf.testrunner/2 = 201510222201</explicitValue>
```